# 'Lack of Side' as used by Dick White, former Intelligence Chief of MI5 and MI6

Tags: british-english

> During Dick White's post-Oxford academic career he traveled to Ann Arbor, Michigan in 1928 to continue studying history at the University of Michigan. Upon arrival at the campus White was warmly greeted by the President and other officers of the university. In Tom Bower's biography of Dick White, 'The Perfect English Spy' White is described as being overwhelmed by his hosts' **'lack of side'** and 'the American way'. He was genuinely impressed with his hosts' spirit of generosity and equality.

**'Lack of side'** didn't appear in any slang dictionaries. I interpret it to mean White's hosts did not display any pro-American bias or attitudes of superiority, as might team members of a football club would sing the praises of their own 'side'. Did I get this right?

Comment: Try definition 17 [**here**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/side?showCookiePolicy=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirming StoneyB's answer in the comment above, here is the primary definition of *side* in Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and unconventional English*, eighth edition (1984):

> **side,** n. Conceit, swagger, pretentiousness. Earliest and often *put on side*, to give oneself airs, to 'swank'. [citation from 1878 omitted]Ex *side*, proud, or more prob., as [Ernest] W[eekley, *An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1921)] suggests, by a pun on *put on side* at billiards.

The earliest use of this term that a Google Books search finds is from Richard Dashwood, [*Chiploquorgan, or Life by the Campfire in Dominion of Canada and Newfoundland*](http://books.google.com/books?id=YpEUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA139&dq=%22put+on+side%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LrHyU5bWDKmCjAK-34DwBA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAzgU#v=onepage&q=%22put%20on%20side%22&f=false) (1872):

> The [train] conductor is often a great man in his own estimation, and looks upon the passengers as so many people who, if they could dodge him, would avoid paying their fares. At the same time, although to an Englishman new to the country, these railway servants appear at first rude and brusque in their manners, yet, if he only knows how to manage them, and does not put on "side," they will do all in their power to oblige him.

Three additional instances are recorded in [*New Zealand Parliamentary Debates*](http://books.google.com/books?id=y-8LAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA208&dq=%22put+on+side%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H63yU_SyM-q5iwKQ64GYBA&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22put%20on%20side%22&f=false) for July 23, 1879:

> Mr. SHEEHAN: ... I will say this much for myself : that I believe some of these charges have arisen from the fact that fromthe time I came into office I have been, as a gentleman said to me this day, one of the most accessible members of the Government. I have never, to use a vulgar phrase, "put on 'side.'" from the time I took office I was prepared to meet and do business with every person who came to me on public business.
>
> ...
>
> Mr. WAKEFIELD: ... I will say that for these Ministers, they do not "put on 'side;'" they will speak to anybody ; the "man in the street" can button-hole them.
>
> ...
>
> Honorable gentlemen opposite need not laugh at what I am saying, because this is a serious matter, and one on which I feel very seriously. The Hon. the Native Minister told us, in his usual jaunty manner, that he had never put on "side," as he called it—that is to say, he had never pretended to rise to the dignity attaching to the position of a Minister of the Crown—that he had never looked down on others.

One later occurrence seems to corroborate the Weekley/Partridge hypothesis that the slang term *side* was drawn from billiards. It also answers a longstanding question of my own—namely, What do people in England call the "bending" force given to the trajectory of a billiard ball (or other ball) by striking the ball off-center? From An Oxford Tutor, "[Young Oxford](http://books.google.com/books?id=D8gRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA627&dq=%22put+on+side%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v7XyU-jhJaaKjAL8uoC4BA&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22put%20on%20side%22&f=false)," in *Fraser's Magazine* May 1881):

> The one thing which will effectually secure a man's unpopularity with the undergraduate public is the suspicion of what is termed 'putting on side.' This term 'side,' which in America is translated 'English,' is mischievously vague in its application. It may generally be described as a combination of outward swagger and inward conceit; but the suspicion of 'putting on side'—in Oxford, at all events—attaches itself to various individuals on most contradictory grounds. One man is supposed to 'put on side' because he happens to be shy or reserved, and consequently talks less than his neighbours in general society. Another is held to talk too much, and so to 'put on side;' and there are men who have laboured under the same imputation simply because they happen to walk in a less crab-like fashion than their fellow-creatures. 'Side,' where it does exist, is certainly an objectionable feature of character; but at Oxford, in nine presumed cases out of ten we believe its existence to be purely imaginary.

Comment: Your last paragraph reminds me of an incident I witnessed a few decades ago in Aberdeen (Scotland), where one Aberdonian had clearly had enough of his companion's hypocrisy or airs regarding some matter or other -- I forget the precise details -- and chivvied his friend with "Don't be so *bloody English!*" As an Englishman myself, I found this rather amusing.

Comment: The odd thing is that in the U.S. we commonly refer to the act of intentionally striking a ball off-center in order to make it move in a curving path as "putting some English on it"—but I can't imagine that people in England would use that idiomatic phrase.

Comment: I think you're right about that -- certainly, I don't recall hearing that term when I still lived in Britain. Instead, you'd *put some side-spin* on the ball or *give it some side-spin*.